# How to move a div to left by 200px

Tags: html

left:-200px; @div3 but that didnt work. How to fix it?!

[image]

Comment: Please provide relevant coding demonstrating the problem. Sometimes a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example is helpful too. You [can't just link to your website](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your `position` properly?

```
<div id="thingToMove"></div>

#thingToMove {
    position:absolute;
    left:-200px;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background:#CCC;
}
```

#### See here: http://jsfiddle.net/44RpG/

Comment: `position:absolute; left:-200px;` won't move it left by 200px; it will place it 200px left to the left edge of nearest positioned ancestor.

Comment: You you expect me to **assume** that it has an ancestor, considering there was absolutely no code provided?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to affect surrounding elements (i.e. also move following elements):

```
margin-left: -200px;
```

If you don't want to affect surrounding elements:

```
position: relative;
left: -200px;
```

If you want to remove the element from the normal flow of the document (following elements will take its place):

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: -200px;
```